# NativeScript set autocorrection language

Tags: android, locale, nativescript

I am developing a NativeScript chat app in JavaScript for Android.
It will be used on italian devices, and I need to enable keyboard autocorrect for this language only.

The issue:
while the device language is set to English, autocorrect works, but it doesn't in Italian.

```
<TextField id="messageBox" hint="Scrivi un messaggio..." class="msg-input"
            autocorrect="true" text="{{ testoMessaggio }}" ></TextField>
```

Since I am new to both NativeScript and Android development, I'm probably missing some basic knowledge about device locale language. Still, searching around I couldn't find any answer.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with one of the debugging devices, a Oneplus One, Lineage OS 15.1. Same problem occurs with different NativeScript apps.

Autocorrection works well on other devices and emulators.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible with Android itself. You may either turn it off or on but can not restrict what should appear in suggestions.

Comment: yes, but is should show for Italian as well when device language is set for Italian.

Comment: Yes, that's obvious. But the question was specially when the device language is english and app uses Italian.

Comment: I think OP's problem is when device language is also set to Italian . he says 'while the device language is set to English, autocorrect works, but it doesn't in Italian.'

Answer (score 0):

There is no such method available with [EditText](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText#public-methods) (Native Android component that NativeScript uses to wrap as TextField) however I think you need to provide special instruction with your app. Normally, each time you switch language, the spellcheck dictionary changes as well. However, If that language dictionary available, user might need to download it.

Settings -> Language & Input -> Add-on Dictionaries

Also to note here that if user has disabled the predictive text, app may not have permission to active that.

Check that your languages are selected in 'Languages in types'
Make sure that the "Predictive" option is activated.
Make sure that the "Auto replacement" option is activated.